# Vue Listening to an event

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

```html
 <router-view @loggedIn="changed"></router-view>
```

Hi , I just need to know what is `@loggedIn` in this context of vue js. I can't seem to find this syntax in the documentation. Is this a custom event of loggedIn which calls the changed method?

Comment: Are you using another package (like Adonis)?

Comment: @Dan It is actually possible to emit events from the current router view: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-mcnulty-ovqeg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark

Comment: @tony19 Thanks, I had seen [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/emitting-events-from-vue-router/10136/4) but he was referring to something a little different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` is a shorthand for v-on. See here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand

In your markup it means that you listen to event `loggedIn` emited from `router-view` and use method `changed` as handler of event